# Como utilizar zoom em uma pagina em css ou javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Gostaria de saber como eu faço o site iniciar com zoom de 67% em CSS ou JavaScript?

Comment: Se sua intenção for melhorar a visualização em dispositivos moveis ou em determinadas resoluções não utilize zoom, utilize media query para formular o tamanho do seu layout em determinada resolução.

Comment: Você conseguiu uma resposta para sua pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

Se for em CSS você tem as seguintes propriedades:

- zoom:

  ```
  body {
      zoom: 67%;
  }
  ```
- transform:

  ```
  body {
       transform: scale(0.67); /*0.67 equivale ao 67%*/
  }
  ```

Note que se você esta desenvolvendo uma página mobile e este for o seu problema talvez o problema seja melhor resolvido com a `<meta name="viewport">`.

Desta maneira o você desativa o zoom automatico do mobiles e desativa a escala com o touch:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=.67, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

Se quiser definir uma escala padrão faça assim (o `.67` equivale ao 67%):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.67, minimum-scale=.67, maximum-scale=.67, user-scalable=0">
```

Se quiser ativar a escala faça isso `user-scalable=1` ou remova o `user-scalable=1`

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve resolver:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajustaZoom() {
        document.body.style.zoom = "67%" 
    }
</script>


<body onload="ajustaZoom()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function zoom() {
        document.body.style.zoom = "300%" 
    }
</script>

<body onload="zoom()">
    <h6>content</h6>
</body>
```